# Когда работает скрипт, подвисает игра (отвечает на действия с задержкой)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Нужна ваша помощь. В общем, сделал простенький скрипт (автокликер) для игры, чтобы подбирать быстрее лут, но, когда он запущен, игра работает не очень хорошо. Чувствуются небольшие подвисания, персонаж отвечает на команды через несколько секунд.

Сам код:

```
lut = os.listdir('LOOT')

while True:
 if keyboard.is_pressed('Caps Lock'):
      for f in lut:
          picture = "LOOT/" + f
          button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(picture, confidence = 0.7, region=(609,919, 1341,1076))
          if button:
               pyautogui.click(button)
               pyautogui.sleep(0.05)
          break
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что тут не так?
Все ли у меня правильно?
И подскажите еще, пожалуйста, есть другой способ, чтобы скрипт начинал воспроизводить код после нажатия клавиши, а если ничего не нажимаю, то он бездействовал?

Comment: добавьте скрин где должен происходить поиск и нажатие. возможно на чистом opencv будет быстрее ?

Comment: Там зона поиска небольшая. В целом с кодом все ок? Задумано, что он будет активироваться при зажатии капса, остальное время бездействовать. Что значит чистом opencv?

Comment: в доках Note: You need to have OpenCV . у вас он установлен ?

Comment: Ну, кажется, да